# How to forward in Spring MVC interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I defined view resolver like this:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and I had a interceptor, when some conditions not pass, I want to forward to a jsp page, I implement like this:

```
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/info.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

Above, the page that I want to forward is hard code, I didn't want to do like that, is there any approach that I can get the page from the view resolver?

Comment: In what function of the interceptor to you want to do the forward : prehandle or posthandle ? It should be easy in posthandle but not in prehandle ...

Comment: prehandle, I want to forward in prehandle

Answer (score 9):

If you wanted to forward to a view from a `postHandle` it would have been easier because in `postHandle` you have full access to the ModelAndView.

It is also possible in a `preHandle` method, thanks to the `ModelAndViewDefiningException`, that allows you to ask spring to do itself the forward from anywhere in a handler processing.

You can use it that way :

```
public class ForwarderInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        // process data to see whether you want to forward
        ...
            // forward to a view
            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("forwarded-view");
            // eventually populate the model
            ...
            throw new ModelAndViewDefiningException(mav);
        ...
        // normal processing
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [RedirectAttributes](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/support/RedirectAttributes.html)

NOTE: Redirects are NOT Forwards; see (https://www.baeldung.com/servlet-redirect-forward)

You can do something like

```
 public String handle(Account account, BindingResult result, RedirectAttributes redirectAttrs) {
   return "redirect:/context/info.jsp";
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If we consider you're using SpringMVC and using controllers and you want to redirect to a info.jsp the code should looks like this :

```
@Controller
public class InfoController {

 @RequestMapping(value = "/info", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String info(Model model) {
     // TODO your code here
     return "info";
 }
}
```